# Python : How to compare strings and ignore white space and special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, replace

I want to compare two strings such that the comparison should ignore differences in the special characters. That is,

> Hai, this is a test

Should match with

> Hai ! this is a test  "or" Hai this is a test

Is there any way to do this without modifying the original strings?

Comment: What are 'special characters' in this context? Importantly, are spaces counted? Because then ignoring the '!' leaves two spaces as opposed to the one in the first string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This removes punctuation and whitespace before doing the comparison:

```
In [32]: import string

In [33]: def compare(s1, s2):
    ...:     remove = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
    ...:     return s1.translate(None, remove) == s2.translate(None, remove)

In [34]: compare('Hai, this is a test', 'Hai ! this is a test')
Out[34]: True
```

Comment: It is not Python3 compatible.

Comment: @AdamDobrawy: Use `str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(remove))` as the map (first argument).

Comment: python3.6 error `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> def cmp(a, b):
...     return [c for c in a if c.isalpha()] == [c for c in b if c.isalpha()]
... 
>>> cmp('Hai, this is a test', 'Hai ! this is a test')
True
>>> cmp('Hai, this is a test', 'Hai this is a test')
True
>>> cmp('Hai, this is a test', 'other string')
False
```

This creates two temporary lists, but doesn't modify the original strings in any way.

Comment: Instead of `c in string.letters`, you can use `c.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution for Python 3.*

The solution given by [root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16474928/13903942) is compatible with **Python 2.7** but not **Python 3.***

Here are some quick receipe for it.

1. Using the same solution but trasnpiled for Python 3.* The translate function now takes only one paremeter, which is a mapping table of the ordinals (integers) character to be removed.

import string

```py
    def compare(s1, s2):
        remove = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
        mapping = {ord(c): None for c in remove}
        print(f'Mapping: \n{mapping}')
        return s1.translate(mapping) == s2.translate(mapping)

    check = compare('Hai, this is a test', 'Hai ! this is a test')
    print(check)
```

### Documentatin

- [Translate Python 3.*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)
- [Translate Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd replace the characters you wish to ignore, and then compare them:

```
import re
def equal(a, b):
    # Ignore non-space and non-word characters
    regex = re.compile(r'[^\s\w]')
    return regex.sub('', a) == regex.sub('', b)

>>> equal('Hai, this is a test', 'Hai this is a test')
True
>>> equal('Hai, this is a test', 'Hai this@#)($! i@#($()@#s a test!!!')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare an arbitrary number of strings for alphabetic equivalence,

```
def samealphabetic(*args):
    return len(set(filter(lambda s: s.isalpha(), arg) for arg in args)) <= 1

print samealphabetic('Hai, this is a test',
                     'Hai ! this is a test',
                     'Hai this is a test')
```

Which prints `True`. Should change `<=` depending on what you want to return for no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can first remove the special characters in your two strings, then compare them.

In your example, the special characters are ',','!' and space.

so for your strings:

```
a='Hai, this is a test'
b='Hai ! this is a test'
tempa=a.translate(None,',! ')
tempb=b.translate(None,',! ')
```

then you can just compare tempa and tempb.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you don't want to modify the original strings, you can also do the operation **in-place** and without requiring any extra space.

```
>>> import string
>>> first = "Hai, this is a test"
>>> second = "Hai ! this is a test"
>>> third = "Hai this is a test"
>>> def my_match(left, right):
    i, j = 0, 0
    ignored = set(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] in ignored:
            i += 1
        elif right[j] in ignored:
            j += 1
        elif left[i] != right[j]:
            return False
        else:
            i += 1
            j += 1
    if i != len(left) or j != len(right):
        return False
    return True

>>> my_match(first, second)
True
>>> my_match(first, third)
True
>>> my_match("test", "testing")
False
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Levenshtein metric](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/) to measure distance between two strings. Rank your string comparisons by score. Pick the top *n* matches.